# Accessing Process global variables in scriptTask (jbpm5)

Tags: global-variables, jbpm

I created a simple process definition in jBPM5 with just a single script task. I want to include a `global` variable, say `count` that is `static` in the sense that the same value is shared across the various process instances, however it is not a constant and each instance can update the value, say increment it in the first task of the process. From the script task I want to do this modification (increment) and print it to the stdout. How do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

System.out.println(count);
kcontext.setVariable("count", count + 1);

Comment: Thanks for the response Kris! However, it was my mistake in not specifying the exact scenario, I have corrected the question now! Please let me know the solution!

Answer (score 0):

I myself found the answer with some researching that we need to use `kcontext.getKnowledgeRuntime().setVariable()` and `.getVariable()` for setting and getting a 'static' variable that is shared across process instances. However, it is leading to another question in my mind as to what would happen if the `scriptTask` that uses `setVariable` is called simultaneously by multiple instances! Thanks @KrisV! Without your help I would not have been able to come to this. :)

Comment: Note that you don't necessarily have to use .getVariable(name), as the variables are automatically injected (but you have to use .setVariable() is you want to change the value).

Comment: If you're talking about a global, you probably should use kcontext.getKnowledgeRuntime().setGlobal(name, value).  If multiple process instances would attempt to write a global value, it would simply use the latest value.  To avoid race conditions, you might want to avoid using multiple threads on the same ksession in that case.